# Incompatible shape in R-keras

Tags: r, keras, audio, conv-neural-network, classification

I'm trying to do audio classification using R-Keras but I have a problem with an incompatible shape error of my network.
I've created these 2 functions in order to read all the wave files and transform them in a matrix using mel features

```
  audio = readWave(paste(outDir, '/', labels$filename[i], sep = ('') ))
  audio = normalize(audio)
  audio = crop(audio) #in order to have all signals of same size
  return(melfcc(audio, sr = audio@samp.rate))
}

load_data = function(){
  features = lapply(1:nrow(labels), function(i) mfcc_extractor(i))
  data_array = array(data = unlist(features), dim = c(206, 12, 1440) )
  set.seed(0)
  train_idx = sample(1:nrow(labels), size = round(nrow(labels)*.8), replace = F) 
  test_idx = c(1:nrow(labels))[-train_idx] 
  
  X_train = data_array[1:206, 1:12, train_idx]
  X_test = data_array[1:206, 1:12, test_idx]
  y_train = labels[train_idx, ]
  y_test = labels[test_idx]
  return(list(X_train = X_train, X_test = X_test, y_train = y_train, y_test = y_test))
}
```

Then I reshape train and test arrays in order to feed them into neural network

```
library(keras)

train_images = array_reshape(X.train_X.test$X_train, c(1152, 12, 206, 1))
test_images = array_reshape(X.train_X.test$X_test, c(288, 12, 206, 1))

train_labels = to_categorical(X.train_X.test$y_train$Actor.id)
test_labels = to_categorical(X.train_X.test$y_test$Actor.id)
```

And after building the network, when I fit it, R give me back this message:

````
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(5, 5), activation = "relu",
                input_shape = c(206, 12, 1)) %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) 

model <- model %>%
  keras_model_sequential()
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 8, activation = "softmax")

model

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "rmsprop",
  loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)


model %>% fit(
  train_images, train_labels
)```


WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 206, 12, 1) for input Tensor("sequential_4_input:0", shape=(None, 206, 12, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 12, 206, 1).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 206, 12, 1) for input Tensor("conv2d_1_input:0", shape=(None, 206, 12, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 12, 206, 1).
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:532 train_step  **
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:205 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_we
````

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there is a shape incompatibility issue between the shape indicated as input to the model and the actual shape of the data. For example, your training data has shape `(None, 12, 206, 1)`, while the shape being indicated as input in the model is `(None, 206, 12, 1)`. Thus, you need to: 1) either change the `input_shape` of the model to `(None, 12, 206, 1)` by doing

```
layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(5, 5), activation = "relu",
                input_shape = c(12, 206, 1))
```

or 2) reshape your training and test data into `(None, 206, 12, 1)` using

```
train_images = array_reshape(X.train_X.test$X_train, c(1152, 206, 12, 1))
test_images = array_reshape(X.train_X.test$X_test, c(288, 206, 12, 1)
```

Comment: Not working... Actually it is the same thing that I did, I cannot find the differences

Comment: The difference is in the order of the dimensions of the array, check the order of 206 and 12.

Comment: Doesn't work anyway... Any other idea? Even if I flat the array and feed into a FFNN keras give me back an error.

Comment: Maybe you can check if the output shape of the model matches the shape of the labels.